# Render icon and text together from server in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, font-awesome

I cannot manage to have html text and icon together rendered by the Shiny server in the main panel unless I render the icon in the UI independently of the server as well. Here is a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Icon test app"),
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
          htmlOutput("restart"),

          h3("Refresh icon from ui()",icon("refresh"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 observe({ output$restart = renderText(

    paste0("<h3>",
           "Refresh icon from server()",
           icon("refresh"),
           "</h3>"
    )
  )
 })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Now the same example without the text and icon rendered by the ui, which shows then the text rendered by the server alone, i.e. without icon:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Icon test app"),
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
          htmlOutput("restart"),

          # h3("Refresh icon from ui()",icon("refresh"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 observe({ output$restart = renderText(

    paste0("<h3>",
           "Refresh icon from server()",
           icon("refresh"),
           "</h3>"
    )
  )
 })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `icon()` when run inside the ui function adds an html dependency to the rendering layer. If you just use the `icon()` function in the server, the dependency isn't added to the html. You can fix this by manually injecting the dependency into your UI. Add `fontawesome::fa_html_dependency()` to your UI layout. For example this should work:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fontawesome::fa_html_dependency(),
  titlePanel("Icon test app"),
  sidebarLayout(    
    sidebarPanel(
    ),    
    mainPanel(      
      htmlOutput("restart")
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is:

```
icon("refresh", lib = "glyphicon")
```

Boostrap has `glyphicon` loaded per default contrary to `fontawesome`.

Within `paste` that converts `HTML` to `character`, `fontawesome` is not loaded automatically. That's why it is working in your first example where there is also an `HTML` icon loading the required library.